# A lot of warnings with webpack uglify

Tags: gulp, webpack, stylus, gulp-uglify

When I'm running webpack uglify plugin and I'm getting a lot of warnings from the stylus loader / css-loader. How can I resolve them? The webpack bundles it successfully.

```
   Condition always true [./~/style-loader!./~/css-loader!./~/stylus-loader!./app/<filename>.styl:10,0]
```

Comment: What kind of warnings? Please edit your question to contain a sample...

Comment: its there... "Condition always true..."

Answer (score 4):

That's normal -- by default Uglify tells you about the dead code that it strips out. If you don't want those "warnings" output, you can configure the plugin not to:

```
new Webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ 
    compress: {
        warnings: false
    }
});
```