# Webpack UglifyJS still giving warning messages

Tags: javascript, webpack, aurelia, uglifyjs

[A lot of warnings with webpack uglify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35456949/a-lot-of-warnings-with-webpack-uglify)

I've turned off warnings in UglifyJS, but I'm still getting a few warnings from webpack.

```
WARNING in main-0.2.8.js from UglifyJs
Dropping unused variable e [./~/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.js:29,292]
Dropping unused variable o [./~/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.js:29,292]
Dropping unused variable i [./~/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.js:29,292]
Non-strict equality against boolean: == false [./~/aurelia-pal-browser/dist/commonjs/aurelia-pal-browser.js:200,0]
Non-strict equality against boolean: == false [./~/aurelia-pal-browser/dist/commonjs/aurelia-pal-browser.js:208,0]
```

Plugins from webpack.config

```
  plugins: [
    new AureliaWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Aurelia webpack skeleton - ' + pkg.version,
      template: 'index.prod.html',
      filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jquery: 'jquery',
      "windows.jquery": 'jquery'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  ]
```

If someone knows how to get rid of those last few warnings that would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you minimize throught UglifyJs, it warns you that it removes unused variables, and that it changes `false` values in `!1` and `true` to `!0`. This is not a problem, it is only to reduce the file length. See also  [Javascript minification why is false replaced with !1 and true with !0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567523/javascript-minification-why-is-false-replaced-with-1-and-true-with-0).
However, you may try to specify compression options to remove these warnings:

```
    compress: {
        warnings: false,
        booleans: false,
        unused: false
    }
```

For more information, see https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#compressor-options. I hope it helps.